# C# do something based on image detection

Tags: c#, image, detection

I am making a program in C#. I want it to do something if image is detected on screen. For example let's say I am making a game bot. And my health is image on my screen filled with green color like so:

[FULL HP BAR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BuJT.jpg)

And something took my hp to this level:

[TAKEN HP BAR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i4Jf.jpg)

If the C# detects the image with hp taken, do something ... Is this possible and how can i do it ? Thanks.

Comment: OP is not writing a game, he seems to be trying to make a game bot

Comment: He is she and yes, she is trying to write a game bot, so whats the big deal ???

Comment: StackOverflow encourage us to provide some useful comment when we downvote some question. Why do they do so? I tell you why? Because objective here to help people to get better especially the new comers. If we know something is not right why can't we eduate the one who does it? Now how on earth answer seeker will know what's wrong with her question. I wonder why people do something because they can not because they should. And I have an adjusted guess someome will ask me what does my comment has to do with question? Its off topic. Well it isn't because I don't see any gesture of help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the bot for game. To detect when life become low you can scan a certain pixel color and test it with the sample value (for example you can capture pixel in the middle of your rectangle and if it is green you have more then half of life).

Also I made screenshots, cut some areas and kept them as bitmaps. In a game I loaded them, then I made screenshot every second and checked if some of these bitmaps appeared in the screenshot.

To capture the screen in C# you can use CopyFromScreen method of Graphics:

```
var screen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                        PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screen );
graphics.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                        0, 0,
                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                        CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```